# Super Resolution: convolutions leaving traces on edges

Tags: image, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

So I've been working on a Super-Resolution model and I've achieved decent results. However, I have remnants of the network left in the output image: I couldn't feed the whole image as input for memory reasons, which meant I had to chop an image as multiple smaller parts (in my case, `128x128`).

The edges of these chops are creating lines for some reason. My question is: **what is the reason and how to prevent that?**

My first thought is that the convolutions on the edge don't have as much information as the rest since padding is required for filters of size exceeding `1x1` so it's normal and unavoidable to have such lines without post-processing. What might be a good post-processing approach?

Or would more training eventually solve that issue?

Another idea I've had is to feed overlapping regions of the image to the network and to replace the edges of one output with the corresponding non-edge part of the overlap-output.

Here is the model I'm using:

```
def setUpModel(x_train, y_train):

    filters = 256
    kernel_size = 3
    strides = 1
    scale_fact = 4
    res_blocks = 3
    img_depth = 3


    # Head module
    input = Input(shape=(None, None, img_depth))  # None = can take inputs of different sizes
    conv0 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(input)

    # Body module
    res = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(conv0)
    act = ReLU()(res)
    res = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(act)
    res_rec = Add()([conv0, res])

    for i in range(res_blocks):
        res1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(res_rec)
        act  = ReLU()(res1)
        res2 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(act)
        res_rec = Add()([res_rec, res2])

    conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(res_rec)
    add  = Add()([conv0, conv])

    # Tail module
    conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(add)
    act  = ReLU()(conv)
    up   = UpSampling2D(size=scale_fact if scale_fact != 4 else 2)(act)  # TODO: try "Conv2DTranspose"

    # When it's a 4X factor, we want the upscale split in two procedures
    if(scale_fact == 4):
        conv = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same')(up)
        act  = ReLU()(conv)
        up   = UpSampling2D(size=2)(act)  # TODO: try "Conv2DTranspose"

    output = Conv2D(filters=3,
                    kernel_size=1,
                    strides=1,
                    padding='same')(up)

    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)

    return model
```

Here are two examples:

[image: HR1]

[image: traces1]

[image: HR2]

[image: traces2]

**EDIT**: As requested, here is the `train` code:

```
def train(model, x_train, y_train):
    print("Training is starting.")

    if load_model == False:
        print("Compiling the model since it wasn't loaded from memory.")
        optimizer = Adadelta(lr=1.0,
                             rho=0.95,
                             epsilon=None,
                             decay=0.0)
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                      loss='mean_squared_error')

    model.fit(x_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=6,  # TODO: is it multi-fold testing?
              verbose=verbosity,
              shuffle=False,
              validation_split=0.1,
              batch_size=7,
              callbacks=get_callbacks())
```

I used to have a `batch_size` of 1 and would train on samples of `128x128` (larger would bust my memory) but that gave me very long training times. I eventually settled for a batch size of 7 and training input size of `64x64`.

The dataset was so large that I had to split it in multiple sub-parts because I couldn't load it all into memory hence the low epochs value (I manually changed the input's source folder before launching the training session again on the saved model).

`get_callbacks()` returns `[]` because some callbacks that I wanted to try using were causing memory problems and slowing down the training time too much (TensorBoad, for example).

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/payne911/SR-ResCNN-Keras-) if you're ever interested in seeing more code to understand.

Comment: Can you tell us what process you used for the training setup? Maybe by reducing the batch size you can then increase the image fragments. Also, in theory you should be able to simply train on lower resolutions, and later use the full resolution during test time to see whether that has also good results.

Comment: I've updated my OP with the training code. What you've suggested has already been tried. But plugging a `2000x1000` image in my GPU's memory causes memory errors so despite training with `64x64` images (batch size of 7), I predict with batch size of 1 and input size of `128x128` and save the results one by one in a variable until the whole image has been processed (predicted) to finally merge all the pieces back together for the actual result.

Comment: You also don't necessarily have to do inference on your GPU (although it is much faster, you can potentially do away with this slower inference, but still keep the results in memory.

Comment: By "inference on your GPU" do you mean using the GPU for predictions? Considering the time it took to process a big image with the GPU, I think I would try to stay away from CPU as much as possible. :p